# Perl command to replace the string based on position

Tags: perl

I need to check if the 300th character is `{`. If yes, it needs to be replaced with 0. Also make a negative decimal number considering 10 digits before `{`. Example: if the input is `111123456789{`, the output will be `11-112345678.90`.

My *sample* input is:

```
H009704COV2009084    PHD0000001H009700204COV2009084    PROD2015122016010418371304COVH009704COV2009084    PTR0000001H0097002C00000000140000000043610000003408092A0000000068061C0000000000000{0000002939340H0000000537585H0000003476926F0000001218378G0000000040292E0000000016497{0000000000827E0000001880498{9000000320436J000000004391000000001606000000000030000000000128000000000006000000004227000000000000000000000000            00000140              0000000000000{0000000000773B0000000000000{000000000000
```

Here the 300th character is `{`. So if I replace this by 0 and converts it to a negative decimal, the expected output will be:

```
H009704COV2009084    PHD0000001H009700204COV2009084    PROD2015122016010418371304COVH009704COV2009084    PTR0000001H0097002C00000000140000000043610000003408092A0000000068061C0000000000000{0000002939340H0000000537585H0000003476926F0000001218378G0000000040292E0000000016497{0000000000827E000-000188049.809000000320436J000000004391000000001606000000000030000000000128000000000006000000004227000000000000000000000000            00000140              0000000000000{0000000000773B0000000000000{000000000000
```

I can do this by using a sed command:

```
sed -e 's/\ (.\ {1,255\ }\ )\ (.\ {1,34\ }\ )\ (.\ {1,9\ }\ )\ ([^{]*\ ){/\1\2+\3.\40/'
```

But the performance is bad when the input file has a huge number of records (~80,000). How can I convert the above sed command to Perl for the same functionality?

Comment: Do you want a command to execute from a terninal -- one-liner?  What does it mean "_converting to negative decimal_"?  You replace `{` by `0` and then ... make it what?

Comment: Since I am new to Perl , I am not sure if one line command is available to do the above functionality. whenever { is found in string it need to be replaced with 0 also make a negative decimal number considering 10 digits before {. ex: if input is 111123456789{, output will be 11-112345678.90

Comment: OK, got it, but -- is the comma in your example above indeed between 8 and 9 (`8.90`) or perhaps after 9, `89.0` ?

Comment: sorry comma is not a part of input. Input is just 111123456789{ and expected output is 11-112345678.90

Comment: That's fine, that is what I meant, in output.  So it is one character further to the left from where `{` is.  So that `1234{` --> `123.40` (and minus ten places to the left).  i'll post in a minute, let me know how it looks.

Comment: Yes, This looks correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function in Perl. It finds a string inside of another, by its offset (position) and length. It can optionally replace it, by another argument. It returns the sought substring.

The needed transformation here is a bit complicated so it involves multiple uses of `substr`, and some counting. The `-` need be inserted 10 positions to the left, and the decimal period/comma at two positions to the left.  Finally, the `{` itself gets replaced. Note that position counting starts with 0, for the first character.

To see how this works, use the example from the comment, which is

```
111123456789{  -->  11-112345678.90
```

In this case `{` is at position 12.

```
echo "111123456789{" | perl -pe'
   $x = substr($_, 2, 9); substr($_, 2, 9, "-$x."); substr($_, 14, 1, "0")'
```

(This need be either copy-pasted or entered on a single line at a terminal; it is broken over two lines here for readability.)  The `$_` above is Perl's 'default' variable carrying what is currently being processed, so here it is the input string. This prints `11-112345678.90` as specified.

The first command extracts the string between positions, where the `-` and `.` need be entered, which starts at 10 positions to the left of position 12 (so, at 2) and is of length 9.  Then that substring is written back there, now padded with `-` and `.`.  Finally the `{` is replaced by `0`.

---

**An alternative use of `subtstr`**

While the above allows more general transformations, for the exact task of inserting characters one can simply add `-` and `.` at given positions, by using `0` for length of a substring to replace.  The replacement of `{` is done as above.

```
perl -pe 'substr($_, 2, 0, "-"); substr($_, 12, 0, "."); substr($_, 14, 1, "0")'
```

This way `$_` is changed each time, and finally printed by courtesy of `-p` switch (see end). Since the first insertion adds a character, the second one needs to happen at one position further down the string.

Note that this isn't more efficient. While it avoids creating a new string `$x`, it changes the string one extra time. Rewriting any part of the string, except for an exact character replacement, means that at least the rest of string has to be saved away and then copied back. For longer strings this is more expensive and this approach may be less efficient. However, this is not going to be noticeable except if *many* such operations are run, or in benchmarks.

---

To apply this to the actual problem, we have 299 instead of 12:

```
perl -pe
   '$x = substr($_, 289, 9); substr($_, 289, 9, "-$x."); substr($_, 301, 1, "0")'
   input_file.txt
```

The second example above can be used as well, with suitably adjusted numbers.

[Switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#Command-Switches) and special variables:

- `-e` indicates that what follows inside `'...'` is to be executed by Perl as a program
- `-p` loops over lines of input and runs the program in `''` on each. The lines may come for instance from a file, if given on the command line, which is automatically opened and lines fed to this program. This is just like `-n` does, but the `-p` also prints the `$_` after the program processed the line (we don't need to say `print`)
- `$_`, "[the default input and pattern-searching space](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_)," has the current line of input

---

This can also be done with a regex. See [the answer by PerlDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206776/perl-command-to-replace-the-string-based-on-position/37219067#37219067).

---

**NOTE**

The above programs are wrong in the sense that they go through with all processing, changing the string, *even if `{` isn't where it is sought*, what is the explicit condition in the question.

Instead, we'd have to first check whether `{` is indeed at the given position, and then do the above.  This is clearly easy to add but then it all becomes even clumsier and slower. Instead, I'd rather recommend a regex-based solution, like the one in [the answer by PerlDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206776/perl-command-to-replace-the-string-based-on-position/37219067#37219067).

Or perhaps a faster way (as commented below that answer)

```
pos($string) = 290;
$string =~ s/\G ([0-9]{9}) ([0-9]) \{ /-$1.${2}0/x;
```

By setting [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos) first, the [`\G` assertion](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions) will make the regex engine start at that position. Then it separately matches 9 and 1 digits, followed by `{`, and replaces them as needed. If `{` *isn't there* then the whole match fails and the string is left unchanged.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you very much for cleaning up and thus improving this answer, one of my early posts here.  (This also drew my attention to it and to a few more needed adjustments.)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand the question and your input line, say `$line`, this pattern gives me your desired result:

```
$line =~ s/^(.{289})    # Start and then 289 arbitrary chars -> $1
            (\d{9})     # Nine digits                           -> $2
            (\d)        # Another 10th digit                 -> $3
            \{          # Literal '{' at pos. 300
          /${1}-${2}.${3}0/x;
```

The replacement is then the first 289 characters, a minus sign, the next 9 digits, a dot, the 10th digit, and a 0 (zero) (and the remaining stuff is kept unchanged).

Comment: Good to have a regex here as well.  Since OP mentioned performance (and in general) it'd be good to not capture-and-copy all ~300 chars, but only replace what's needed, say using `pos` and `\G`.  For example along the lines of  `perl -wE '$s = "123abc"; pos($s) = 3; $x =~ s/\G(.)/X/; say $s'`, replacing one char after position 3, so `a` becomes `X`.  The `\G` matches at `pos` (search for 'pos' or go to "Assertions" in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)).  I think your code can just go in, instead of `3` and single char capture and replacement in oneliner (tested on shorter example).

Comment: @zdim Sounds reasonable. I never thought of _setting_ `pos()` but it's really a good idea. Thank you.